# Storing object as JSON and accessing it in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an object containing a list and I want to plot a chart using values from that list in my view using High Chart. The problem is that I am using JavaScript and I cant access my model from the JavaScript.
Here is my model code.

```
 public class MortgageCalculator
{
  public List<double> interest_month = new List<double>();

  public void calculations()
  {
  for(int i=1;i<=this.nPer;i++)
        {
            this.interest_month.Add(Math.Round(-Financial.IPmt((this.interest / 12) / 100, Convert.ToDouble(i), this.nPer, this.loan_amount),2));
        }
   }
}
```

Controller Code:
I get values from the user for calculation, updates my model and then redirects to Results page that is supposed to show the chart of interest values

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult M_Calculator()
    {
        var mortgageCalculator = new MortgageCalculator();
        return View(mortgageCalculator);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult M_Calculator(MortgageCalculator mortgageCalculator)
    {    
        UpdateModel(mortgageCalculator);

        //call calculation functions here
        mortgageCalculator.Amortization();


        return View("Results",mortgageCalculator);

    }
```

My View Code:

```
@model Calculators.Models.MortgageCalculator
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Results";
}


@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/lineChart.js")\

<div id="container" style="min-width:310px; height:400px; margin:0 auto">
    @section scripts
    {
        <script src="~/Scripts/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/highcharts.src.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/lineChart.js"></script>
    }

</div>
```

I want to access the list from the model in my JavaScript lineChart.js and plot the chart. I think I need to use JSON but I don't know how. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: You can convert your list to a javascript array using `var values = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.interest_month))`

Comment: How would I access in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two ways. One is to use jQuery to retrieve the JSON object and change your Action to return a JsonResult (the easier way IMO). The other way is to create the JavaScript object by creating the string using C#.

**1. Using jQuery to retrieve JSON object**

Change your Action to return Json instead of a View.

```
public ActionResult M_Calculator()
{
    var mortgageCalculator = new MortgageCalculator();
    mortgageCalculator.calculations();
    return Json(mortgageCalculator.interest_month); // return only the array
}
```

In your View, you can use jQuery to retrieve the JSON object like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var calcURL = '@Url.Action("M_Calculator", "MyController")';
    var interestMonthsArray = [];
    $.getJSON(calcURL, function (data) {
         interestMonthsArray = data;
    });
</script>
```

**2. Use C# to create JSON object**

In your View:

```
@model Calculators.Models.MortgageCalculator
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Results";
  bool first = true;
  string arrStr = "[";
  foreach (var month in Model.interest_month)
  {
     if (first)
     {
       first = false; 
     }
     else
     {
        arrStr += ",";
     }
     arrStr += month;
  }
  arrStr += "]";
}
....
<script type="text/javascript">
   var interestMonthsArray = @arrStr;
</script>
```

Of course, you can also create this string in your Action or even in your model class.

Comment: Can I redirect it to a specific view like return View("Results",mortgageCalculator); here I am redirecting to Results View. And one other question is that how can I retrieve the model data in my view. Lets say I want to populate a table in my View with the model data.

Comment: @user3367327 Are you using method 1 or 2? As for how to use the data to create a table, there's many tutorials on the web for that.